# Constraints on a polygon in 3D

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I have a 3D geometry related question. Suppose you have a polygon in 3D, determined by the cartesian coordinates of its points $(x_1, .... x_n)$, and edges $((x_1,x_2), \dots, (x_{n-1},x_n), (x_n, x_1))$.
Suppose that you fix:

- $\forall i \in [1,n-1]$ , the distances $|x_{i+1} - x_i|$, and ${|x_1 - x_n|}$
- $\forall i \in [1,n-1]$ , the bond angles $\widehat{x_{i-1}x_ix_{i+1}}$ and $\widehat{x_{n}x_1x_{2}}$

Does this ***uniquely*** determine the shape of the possible 3D polygon ?

**Some thoughts**

Since we need $n$ points to define our polygon, we need to determine $3n$ variables (the $x$, $y$ and $z$ variables).

The constraints on distances give us $n$ equations.

The constraints on the bond angles give us $n$ equations.

And because our 3D polygon can rotate and translate in space, we center it around $(0,0,0)$, and fix a vector of spherical coordinates $(\phi, \psi)$ for it. So that is $5$ more equations.
So in total we have $2n + 5$ equations.

My questions is : did I miss some constraints ? Why am I obtaining $2n+5$ and not $3n$ ? It feels intuitive that fixing the bond length and bond angles should give a unique 3D shape, could you give me your thoughts on this ?

**For those familiar with torsion angles**

Instead of characterizing the polygon with cartesian coordinates, we can use spherical coordinates as above, with distances $|x_{i+1} - x_i|$, bond angles, and torsion angles. Another way of putting the question is, does determining the distances and bond angles determine the torsion angles.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: You also know all your points lie on the same plane. That's $n-3$ more equations.

Comment: @Intelligenti Pauca Does the polygon lies in a plane ? Nothing is said about that...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I rather suspect they’re not assumed to be coplanar, especially since OP mentions torsion angles. Let’s hear what they have to say about that

Comment: If it doesn't lie on a plane then it's obvious it isn't determined. Moreover, I wouldn't call it a polygon.

Comment: No they don't necessarily lie in the same plane ! they're not coplanar, that's why I call it a 3D polygon

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Let us consider the case of an **initialy planar** polygon with $10$ sides (see figure below) arranged so as to form a star with 5 branches with angles $\widehat{x_{i-1}x_ix_{i+1}}$ alternately equal to $2 \pi /3$ and $-\pi/3$.

One can turn it into a **skew polygon** for example by rotating vertex $x_2$ in a space rotation by any angle around line $x_1x_3$ without modifying angle $\widehat{x_{1}x_2x_{3}}$, and without modifying any length...

[image]

Comment: I think you should add this is a [skew polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_polygon), to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca I agree. I just made the modification.

Comment: Right, nice example ! I feel like this happens because your axis of rotation for that portion of the polygon intersects with the neighboring edges to that portion. But otherwise it would not be true. I wonder if this is a sufficient and necessary condition

Comment: This condition of "neighboring edges" is not sufficient : you could for example do the same thing by rotating $a_3$ with a rotation with axis $a_1a_5$

Comment: I think your example with $a_3$ works, but not the one with $a_2$. After a half rotation, won't the figure be planar again but with the $a_2$ vertex convex now? Certainly by then the angles $a_{10}a_1a_2$ and $a_2a_3a_4$ have changed

Comment: Or perhaps you mean that we can do the rotation while continuously deforming the whole star in a suitable way?

Comment: Jean Marie was only talking about the a3 case I think, and it s a sufficient counter example to my claim above