# Number of possible configurations of a 3D-polygon with given edge-lengths and angles between consecutive edges

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I have again a 3D geometry question. Suppose you have a 3D-polygon , determined by the cartesian coordinates of its points $(x_1, .... x_n)$, and edges $((x_1,x_2), \dots, (x_{n-1},x_n), (x_n, x_1))$. Note that the points of the 3D-polygon **are not necessarily coplanar**.

Suppose that you fix:

- $\forall i \in [1,n-1]$ , the distances $|x_{i+1} - x_i|$, and ${|x_1 - x_n|}$
- $\forall i \in [1,n-1]$ , the bond angles $\widehat{x_{i-1}x_ix_{i+1}}$ and $\widehat{x_{n}x_1x_{2}}$

Under this hypothesis, what is the number of valid configurations of this 3D-polygon ? Is it unique or is there an infinity of such configurations?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Is this question different from your previous one to which I had given an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719028/305862) ?

Comment: Hi again Jean-Marie ! It is a more general question, you gave a nice counter example for a case where there is an infinity of such configurations, but this is a special case, and I was wondering given any 3D polygon, how many configurations we can have? Thanks for your help !